# Tracking user activity in openvz container?

Tags: security, openvz, pci-dss

I have been trying to figure out a way to track user activity in an openvz container for a long time now (auditd like in KVM's). This is a PCI-DSS requirement. I can't seem to find any good alternatives. I was hoping someone out there was using openvz in a PCI-DSS environment that could lend me some knowledge.

Comment: What about using auditd on the hardware node?